# View queried data on Controller to VIews

Tags: php, laravel

This code works on some part of my program but I wonder why I get errors on this one. Here is my code

Controller

```
        $mydate=Carbon::now()->addHours(8);
        $newdate=$mydate->toDateString();

        $myquery=DB::table('attendances')
        ->leftJoin('employees', 'attendances.user_id', '=', 'employees.id')
        ->where('date_only', '=', $newdate)
        ->orderBy('attendances.logon','asc')->get();

            return View::make('home')->with($myquery);
```

View

```
 <table >
              <tr>

            <td>
              First Name
            </td>
            <td >
                Last Name
            </td>
            <td>
                Time in
            </td>
              </tr>
           @foreach ($myquery as $mytask) 
                <tr>
                     <td >
        {{$mytask->firstname}}
                    </td>
                    <td >
                      {{$mytask->lastname}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                          {{$mytask->logon}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
             @endforeach
            </table>
```

I've been working on this for hours, but I just cant fin the error, I always get error 500, PLease Help

Here's a var_dump of $myquery

> array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#156 (11) { ["user_id"]=> int(21)
>   ["logon"]=> string(19) "2014-11-28 08:11:12" ["logoff"]=> string(19)
>   "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["date_only"]=> string(19) "2014-11-28 00:00:00"
>   ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2014-11-24 07:21:06" ["updated_at"]=>
>   string(19) "2014-11-24 07:21:06" ["in_out"]=> int(1) ["id"]=> int(21)
>   ["firstname"]=> string(4) "Jake" ["lastname"]=> string(5) "balba"
>   ["position"]=> string(6) "awdwad" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#157 (11) {
>   ["user_id"]=> int(22) ["logon"]=> string(19) "2014-11-28 08:11:17"
>   ["logoff"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["date_only"]=>
>   string(19) "2014-11-28 00:00:00" ["created_at"]=> string(19)
>   "2014-11-24 08:55:04" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2014-11-24
>   08:55:04" ["in_out"]=> int(1) ["id"]=> int(22) ["firstname"]=>
>   string(9) "Charmaine" ["lastname"]=> string(5) "Balba" ["position"]=>
>   string(10) "Programmer" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#158 (11) {
>   ["user_id"]=> int(23) ["logon"]=> string(19) "2014-11-28 08:11:27"
>   ["logoff"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["date_only"]=>
>   string(19) "2014-11-28 00:00:00" ["created_at"]=> string(19)
>   "2014-11-25 07:21:31" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2014-11-25
>   07:21:31" ["in_out"]=> int(1) ["id"]=> int(23) ["firstname"]=>
>   string(3) "Kim" ["lastname"]=> string(7) "Samsung" ["position"]=>
>   string(10) "Programmer" } }

Comment: is your debug set to `true` in your app -> config -> app.php file?

Comment: you might also look at the app -> storage -> logs -> laravel.log file

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet but what does your server log say? 500 error should generate a line in the server error log.

Comment: yes, but there should be an error log on your server that says why that 500 error was generated. If you are using PHP/Apache it would be in /var/log/apache2/error.log near the bottom. Find the error log and let us know what the last few lines say.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing 2nd param to `with` method:

```
$tasks = DB::table('attendances')
    ->leftJoin('employees', 'attendances.user_id', '=', 'employees.id')
    ->where('date_only', '=', $newdate)
    ->orderBy('attendances.logon','asc')->get();

return View::make('home')->with('tasks', $tasks);

// then view:
@foreach ($tasks as $task)
```